# How to customize the pdf of a given page?

Tags: html, css, pdf

I would like to ask if it is possible to somehow adapt the page so that it is in normal form, but when I create a pdf page so that I only have the content I need and I want to have there. So I'll make an example on my site. There is a menu on the left side of my page and the main content of that page is on the right, when I create a pdf page so there is also a menu that is completely useless there and I don't want it there, so when I create a pdf I will have only those applications without of that menu only the main content. Don't know how to do it? Maybe there will be some js library or something in css. Thank you for your help

For example, you can look at my page:
http://litecode.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you are making pdfs. If you are using some kind of virtual printer (like save to pdf that is on windows and Chromebook and maybe mac) then you can use a media query. Here is an example:

```css
@media print {
    /* Do what you want here */

    nav {
       display: none;
    }
}
```